# How do I manage python versions in source control for application?

Tags: python, version-control, virtualenv, pyenv

We have an application that uses pyenv/virtualenv to manage python dependencies. We want to ensure that everyone who works on the application will have the same python version. Coming from ruby, the analog is Gemfile. To a certain degree, .ruby-version.

What's the equivalent in python? Is it .python-version? I've seen quite a few .gitignore that have that in it and usually under a comment ".pyenv". What's the reason for that? And what's the alternative?

Comment: Do you mean develops on the application or end users?

Comment: @reptilicus  It is the same problem, essentially.  The first thing a developer should do after cloning is to install the application as editable, and then execute the test suite.

Comment: Why not just specify the specific python version when creating the virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of `setuptools` (24.2.0+) allow you to control Python version at the distribution level.

For example, suppose you wanted to allow installation only on a (compatible) version of Python 3.6, you could specify:

```
# in setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    python_requires='~=3.6',
    ...
)
```

The distribution built by this setup would have associated metadata which would prevent installation on incompatible Python version.  Your clients need a current version of `pip` for this feature to work properly, older pip (<9.0.0) will not check this metadata.

If you must extend the requirement to people using older version of `pip`, you may put an explicit check on `sys.version` somewhere in the module level of the `setup.py` file.  However, note that with this workaround, the package will still be downloaded by pip - it will fail later, on a `pip install` attempt with incorrect interpreter version.

Comment: just to confirm, @wim, this isn't just for libraries but also for applications? For example, a web app

Comment: Both libs and apps.  It's valid for anything with a `setup.py`.  And since you mentioned you have dependencies, you should have a `setup.py`.